# Does this Asynchronous Lambda Cryptica Code do what I think?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, lambda

```
    Action<SPItemEventProperties> deleteAction = DeleteWorkspace;
    AsyncCallback deleteDone = deleteAction.EndInvoke;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => deleteAction.BeginInvoke(properties, deleteDone, null));
```

So this is suppose to call DeleteWorkspace Asynchronously and then call EndInvoke when its done, I wrote it but I am not positive it will work properly.  I stepped through and it appears to work but the syntax is making me second guess myself cause I have never seen it done like this on the net...

Comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but to really understand it let's pretend it were written like this:

```
void RunAsync<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    AsyncCallback Done = action.EndInvoke;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() => action.BeginInvoke(properties, Done, null));
}

RunAsync(DeleteWorkspace);
```

Note that in the code above, it looks like the 'Done' callback will go out of scope right away.  However, the compiler will capture (close over) it with a closure, so that it's available when needed.

Comment: Thanks Joel that was my question, I wasn't positive that it would force the use of a closure. How can you verify that btw? Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Any time you pass a variable to a lambda, it uses a closure.  I know it's tricky to start noticing that.

Comment: Yup, that's absolutely the case. For fun, have a look at the decompiled code - that "local variable" will actually be a member of a new class the C# compiler has created for you.

Comment: Mind you, you don't really *need* the "local" variable anyway. You could use deleteAction.EndInvoke directly in the lambda: () => deleteAction.BeginInvoke(properties, deleteAction.EndInvoke, null) should be fine. Without looking, I can't remember whether you'd have to cast it to AsyncCallback or not, but I *suspect* not.